# В чем разница между парсингом(parsing) и скрейпингом(Web Scraping)?

Tags: html, парсер

Все не может дойти до меня в чем разница между этими понятиями. Как я понял и парсинг и скрейпинг вытаскивает информацию из HTML.

Comment: Скрейпинг добывает данные. Парсинг извлекает из добытого то, что нужно.

Answer (score 5):

Парсинг — это синтаксический анализ, разбор текста в синтаксическое дерево в соответствии с формальной грамматикой. Например, по БНФ. Парсинг — обычная стандартная операция в начале компиляции. Слово «парсинг» также применяется к более простым чисто синтаксическим операциям, например вытаскивание числа из его строкового представления.

А вот загрузка веб-страницы и попытка выковырять из неё информацию, обычно из формы, не предназначенной для этого, и в обход API и ограничений, а часто и правил пользования сайтом — это веб-скрейпинг.

Ничего общего.

Comment: @Waleron, смотри более детальное определение (англ.): **parser** vs **crawler** vs **scraper** https://webscraping.pro/crawler-vs-scraper-vs-parser/

Answer (score 1):

Парсер более обобщенный термин чем скрейпинг.

Если говорить в контексте анализа контента сайта и выкачивания из него нужной информации, то есть операция обхода и выкачивания сайта и есть операция анализа полученных страниц и извлечение полезной информации.

Изначально, приложение выполняющее обе операции называлось парсером.

Потом придумали термин краулер и разделили процесс на две самостоятельные операции. Краулер занимается обходом сайта, а парсер анализом содержимого. Иногда, термин краулер использовали для обозначения обеих операций как термин парсер ранее.

Позднее придумали термин скрейпинг. Скрейпинг объединяет в себе функции краулера и парсера.

По сути, изначально скрейпинг и парсинг это было одно и тоже. Сейчас парсинг это одна из функций скрейпинга.